# Additional columns in SELECT Count()

Tags: sql, sql-server

This SQL Server query works

```
SELECT 
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
FROM
    dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.SEM_CLIENT, dbo.SEM_AGENT, dbo.IDENTITY_MAP
WHERE 
    sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID
    and sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID
    and sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    and dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    and dbo.SEM_AGENT.TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  *      CAST(1000 as bigint)
GROUP BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
HAVING COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) > 1
ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESC;
```

But I want to `SELECT` additional columns (to show which computers have the duplicate `COMPUTER_ID`)

```
SELECT 
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME
,   [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
,   dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
,   dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
FROM
    dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.SEM_CLIENT, dbo.SEM_AGENT, dbo.IDENTITY_MAP
WHERE 
    sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID
    and sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID
    and sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    and dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    and dbo.SEM_AGENT.TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  *      CAST(1000 as bigint)
GROUP BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
HAVING COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) > 1
ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESC;
```

I get error

> Column 'dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How to fix?

**UPDATE**: when I execute

```
SELECT 
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME
,   [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
,   dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
,   dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
FROM
    dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.SEM_CLIENT, dbo.SEM_AGENT, dbo.IDENTITY_MAP
WHERE 
    sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID
    and sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID
    and sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
    and dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
    and dbo.SEM_AGENT.TIME_STAMP > DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))  *      CAST(1000 as bigint)
GROUP BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,[IP_ADDR1_TEXT], dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION, dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
HAVING COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) > 1
ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESC;
```

it results in

```
COMPUTER_NAME   IP_ADDR1_TEXT    AGENT_VERSION    COMPUTER_ID          Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
ABC             10.10.10.10       12.1             56604FEE0AF              3
```

But I am looking for

```
COMPUTER_NAME   IP_ADDR1_TEXT    AGENT_VERSION    COMPUTER_ID          Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
ABC             10.10.10.10      12.1               56604FEE0AF             3
123             10.10.10.15      12.2               56604FEE0AF             3
XYZ             10.10.10.25      12.2               56604FEE0AF             3
```

**UPDATE 2**:

I included `FROM` and `WHERE`

Comment: Add COMPUTER_NAME in group by

Comment: Try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26387167/2246380) if you don't want to group by the columns which might reduce the rows in the result which is what happened to you

Comment: Based on your update: do you want to see the duplicates as calculated for each COMPUTER_NAME, or do you want an overall number of duplicates with that same number appearing for each COMPUTER_NAME?

Comment: Also based on the update: nothing in your query would filter out the rows for "123" and "XYZ". Based on what you've shown, they're being filtered out either by whatever's in your WHERE clause, or they're being filtered out by your HAVING clause (their Duplicate_Hardware_IDs values is 1)

Comment: @PhilipKelley Yes, I want overall number of duplicates with that same number appearing for each COMPUTER_NAME. And the "123" and "XYZ" is being filtered out 
by `HAVING` clause, i.e. Duplicate_Hardware_IDs is GREATER than 1

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,
            [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],
            dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION,
            dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, 
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID)
    FROM
    ...
    WHERE 
    ...
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE N > 1
ORDER BY N DESC
```

Comment: Double alias for the `COUNT(*)` with `N=` and `as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs`, aside from that this is the preferred answer imo.

Comment: @GoatCO Oops, you are completely right, sorry about that

Comment: @Lamark it just repeats the field with ABC three times. Can you update this solution

Answer (score 2):

Just include the columns in your `Select` list to `Group By` list

```
SELECT 
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME
,   [IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
,   dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
,   dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
FROM
...
WHERE 
...
GROUP BY 
     dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, 
     dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,
     ...
HAVING COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) > 1
ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESC;`
```

Answer (score 1):

Any column that is in select statement but not in any aggregate function (MIN,MAX,SUM,COUNT,AVG), should come in GROUP BY clause.

```
   SELECT 
         dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME
        ,[IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
        ,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
        ,dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
        ,COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
    FROM
    ...
    WHERE 
    ...
    GROUP BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME
            ,[IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
            ,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION
            ,dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
    HAVING COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) > 1
    ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause as others mentioned or if you don't want to do a group by with thee columns then try the following

```
SELECT 
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,
    [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],
    dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION,
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
FROM dbo.sem_computer c
INNER JOIN
dbo.SEM_AGENT ON //add the join conditions 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
    dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
FROM
 ...
WHERE 
...
GROUP BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
HAVING COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) > 1) temp
ON c.COMPUTER_ID=temp.COMPUTER_ID
ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all non aggregate fields in group by clause:
`GROUP BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,[IP_ADDR1_TEXT]
,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION, dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID`

```
SELECt dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,IP_ADDR1_TEXT,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION,dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs FROM ... WHERE ...GROUP BY dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,IP_ADDR1_TEXT,dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION, dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID HAVING COUNT(dbo.sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) > 1ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your query, as you don't show how you're relating SEM_AGENT to the query.

One option is to add the field to the group by--just add a comma and the field name.
You could also use an aggregate funtion like LAST() where you're returning the field in the query.
You might also be able to use a sub-select to return the field.  I'm not sure about that one, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by JOINing your two queries.  Something like the following should work.

```
;WITH Duplicates AS (
    SELECT 
        sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID, 
        COUNT(sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID) as Duplicate_Hardware_IDs
    FROM
        sem_computer
    WHERE 
        ...
    GROUP BY sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
)
SELECT 
    sem_computer.COMPUTER_NAME,
    sem_computer.[IP_ADDR1_TEXT],
    SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION,
    sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
FROM
        sem_computer
    INNER JOIN
        Duplicates
            ON sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID = Duplicates.COMPUTER_ID
    INNER JOIN
        SEM_AGENT
            ON SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID = sem_computer.COMPUTER_ID
WHERE 
    Duplicates.Duplicate_Hardware_IDs > 1
ORDER BY Duplicate_Hardware_IDs DESC;
```

Find the duplicates first and then JOIN on those and return the additional information.  You will also have to JOIN to the SEM_AGENT table.